# Как проявляется contentDescription

Tags: android, android-layout

В учебнике по Android'у несколько раз упоминается про параметр (и метод) `contentDescription`. К примеру, в разметке я его устанавливал в `ImageView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:contentDescription="LOGO!"
        android:src="@drawable/starbuzz_logo" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/options" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Но я никак не могу понять для чего это! На картинку и нажимал, и удерживал, но никаких эффектов, текста и тд. Так для чего же этот `contentDescription` и как он проявляется?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Это для слабовидящих. Текст в значении этого аттрибута будет озвучен системой при нажатии на картинку в случае, если в настройках устройства включена соответствующая опция.

Озвучка идёт чрез гугловое [приложение](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.marvin.talkback)

Comment: Я бы хотел добавить, что это очень важный аттрибут. Я никогда о нем не задумывался пока мне не написал незрячий человек. Пришлось несколько дней отлаживать всю программу, что бы такие люди могли ей пользоваться. Обычно используют TalkBack. Еще такой момент, есть текст в виде html, так вот для зрячих его видно красиво, а вот TalkBack может начать читать тэги и прочую лабуду. Пришлось и в такие компоненты прописывать чистый текст.