# Предупреждение - android:contentDescription="TODO" для Image

Tags: android, xml, изображения

Неоднократно в Android Studio сталкиваюсь с проблемой **android:contentDescription="TODO"** при добавлении любого PNG изображения в разметку (.xml) **+ Hardcoded Text** ругается. Изображение для кнопки (ImageButton).

Знаю, что нужно сделать описание изображения - но где и как его сделать? (или я неправильно "знаю"?)

Раньше все откладывал разобраться с проблемой, а теперь уже тянуть некуда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этот атрибут прописывается описание картинки, которое может быть озвучено системой, если включена функция соответствующая в [настройках ОС](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506756/17609). Это требуется для слабовидящих.

Вы можете действовать следующим образом:

1. Добавить всюду в этот атрибут нужные строки из ресурсов. Это правильный подход, который избавит вас от предупреждений студии, т.к. будет обеспечена как поддержка озвучивания, так и поддержка мультиязычности.
2. Добавить ко всем `ImageView` `tools:ignore="ContentDescription"` - это уберёт все предупреждения, вам не надо будет писать описания, но слабовидящие будут справедливо называть ваше приложение непригодным для использования.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ) учту эту строку в проекте)